# Laravel Passport API upload multiple images

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-passport

Currently I have single upload of image using `Laravel Passport API`

I have this code and it's working fine.

```
        //Saves file to public folder
        $dateTime = date('Ymd_His');
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $fileName = $dateTime . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $savePath = public_path('/upload/img/');
        $file->move($savePath, $fileName);

        //This saves the current file path of image to mytable
        $ActivityLog = new ActivityLogImg;
        $ActivityLog->actCode = $activity_code;
        $ActivityLog->projCode = $request->projCode;
        $ActivityLog->attachment = "/upload/img/".$fileName;
        $ActivityLog->type = "IMAGE";
        $ActivityLog->deleted = 0;
        $ActivityLog->created_by_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $ActivityLog->created_by_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $ActivityLog->created_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->updated_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->save();

        return response([
            "status"=>"ok",
            "message"=>"Activity successfully submitted!"
        ]);
```

and I have this postman request to test the api and it's working fine

[image]

[image]Now I'm trying to do multiple upload of image in one single request. Is that possible for this code?

Comment: What would be the question? Is that possible? Yes, it is possible. For this code? not exactly, you would have to adapt it to handle multiple files. A simple `foreach($request->file('file') as $file)` might be enough. In postman you can name the inputs as `file[]` instead `file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes can do it same way with your code

in postman pass name as `file[]` as multiple time

```
foreach($request->file('file') as $file){
        $dateTime = date('Ymd_His');
        $fileName = $dateTime . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $savePath = public_path('/upload/img/');
        $file->move($savePath, $fileName);

        //This saves the current file path of image to mytable
        $ActivityLog = new ActivityLogImg;
        $ActivityLog->actCode = $activity_code;
        $ActivityLog->projCode = $request->projCode;
        $ActivityLog->attachment = "/upload/img/".$fileName;
        $ActivityLog->type = "IMAGE";
        $ActivityLog->deleted = 0;
        $ActivityLog->created_by_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $ActivityLog->created_by_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $ActivityLog->created_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->updated_at = now();
        $ActivityLog->save();

}

return response([
        "status"=>"ok",
        "message"=>"Activity successfully submitted!"
    ]);
```